# This code is running but does not shows button and label control

Tags: java

Code does not display the button and label, I have used a panel but it's not working. What should i do? Could someone please tell me what mistake I've made? Also suggest a solution please..

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
public class AnoDemo extends Applet
{
    public void init()
    {
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       Panel p1=new Panel(); 
       Label l=new Label("text");
       Button b=new Button("Click here");
        p1.setVisible(true);
        p1.add(l);
        p1.add(b);
       setBackground(Color.green); 
       addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
       {
           public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
           {
                  setBackground(Color.red);
                  repaint();
           }
           public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                setBackground(Color.green);
                repaint();
            }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont you need at least one frame?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the panel to your applet inside init method after you created the panel. Just add the following line and it will work.

```
    this.add(p1);
```